# android kotlin firestore return 0 value when placed in a non-activity class

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-mvp

is there an issue in putting my firestore snapshotlistener in a non-activity class?
I am trying to add snapshotlistener in my Model (MVP) but it returns 0,
but when I am accessing it in a activity class, it returns with values.

here's my code:

```
override fun fetchJsonToFirestore(activity: Activity) {
    FirebaseFirestore
        .getInstance()
        .collection("devices")
        .addSnapshotListener(activity)
        { querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, e: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
            for (document in querySnapshot!!.documents) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    val notifPojo = document.toObject(Device::class.java!!)
                    mobileList.add(notifPojo!!)
                }
            }
        }

    presenter.mobileList(mobileList)
```

Comment: What you see in your  logcat when you debug your code ?

Comment: Why do you say it returns 0? How do you check that? If you try to log the value of a property inside the callback, is something printed out in the logcat?